# Output pdf file shows empty references after inserting BibTeX in Lyx 2.0.5

Tags: bibtex, lyx, jabref

My output pdf file shows empty references after inserting BibTeX in Lyx 2.0.5. The BibTeX file is created by JabRef 2.9.2 and I am using Windows 7.

Comment: did you run bibtex on the project?

Comment: @ThomWiggers LyX handles that automatically.

Comment: Have you added any citations to your document? Only cited references are added to the reference list.

Comment: no i just save the file as .bib format in jabref and then insert it in lyx

Comment: Sorry i am very new to lyx. cant understand your question. Anyway when i manually insert citations in Lyx then it showed in pdf bt the problem occured when i insert bibtex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Actually in Lyx i dont have to write any code. it automatically generate it.

Comment: You have run into [this](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/2757) 7 year old bug that will be fixed for LyX 2.1 (beta to be released soon). bibtex is probably trying to tell you what's wrong but LyX is not passing that information on. To see the bibtex log, export to LaTeX (pdflatex) and compile manually with pdflatex and bibtex. If you don't understand the error, post it here. And yes, similar to what Papiro says, please post a [LyX minimal example](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample).

Comment: @smf What I meant was: after you have done Insert --> List/TOC this--> BibTeX bibliography, have you added any citations from that bibliography, e.g. with Insert --> Citation?

Answer (score 6):

You have run into [this](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/2757) 7 year old bug that will be fixed for LyX 2.1 (beta to be released soon). bibtex is probably trying to tell you what's wrong but LyX is not passing that information on. To see the bibtex log, export to LaTeX (pdflatex) and compile manually with pdflatex and bibtex. If you don't understand the error, post it here. And yes, similar to what Papiro says, please post a [LyX minimal example](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample).

EDIT: note that the bug was not fixed for LyX 2.1. It was viewed as too intrusive of a change. Many users had documents were compiling and were upset when suddenly they received errors. See the ticket (click on "this" above) for more information.